# SelectList selected value not carried over to DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Razor page with a drop down list inside a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ProductsByOwners", "Report", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "ProductsByOwners" }))
{            
    @Html.Label("Choose product owner: ")
    @Html.DropDownList("OwnerList", (SelectList)ViewBag.OwnerList, new { @onchange = "this.form.submit();" })    
}
```

The selected value of my `SelectList` is not being carried over to the `DropDownList`.  I've debugged and stepped through the code and found that `(SelectList)ViewBag.OwnerList` evaluates properly and has the expected value selected, but the resulting HTML does not have any of the `option` tags selected.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

**UPDATED**

Here is how the SelectList is created in my action:

```
ViewBag.OwnerList = new SelectList(ListUtils.ProductOwners(), "Key", "Value", values["OwnerList"]);
```

The result has the value indicated by `values["OwnerList"]` selected.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the could where you create the selectlist?

Comment: I added an update.  Although, I'm pretty sure the problem is in the View.  I've stepped through the code all the way into the view and the SelectList has a selected value.

Comment: Are you sure the specified value (values["OwnerList"]) exists in the ProductOwners-list? Are the values properly rendered in the select-list?

Comment: Yep. When I add a watch to `ViewBag.OwnerList`, the `SelectedValue` property is the same as `values["OwnerList"]` and when I drill down to that `SelectListItem`, the `Selected` property is `true`.

Comment: What kind of type is 'Key'? Have you tried casting values["OwnerList"] to that specific type?

Comment: Changed to `(string)values["OwnerList"]`.  Same result; the `SelectList` has the correct value selected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not using the DropDownList helper properly. In order to create a dropdownlist you need 2 things:

1. a scalar property to bind to the selected value when the form is submitted
2. a collection to bind the options to

In your example you have only one of those 2 things (the second). Your first argument is called `OwnerList` and you have `ViewBag.OwnerList` passed as second argument.

So:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "SelectedOwnerId", 
    (SelectList)ViewBag.OwnerList, 
    new { @onchange = "this.form.submit();" }
)
```

---

Obviously I would recommend you using strongly typed views ans view models. And obviously get rid of the weakly typed ViewBag/ViewData/ViewCrap.

So start by designing a view model to meet the requirements of your view (which from what you have shown so far is to display a dropdownlist):

```
public class OwnerViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Choose product owner: ")]
    public string SelectedOwnerId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> OwnerList { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class ReportController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult ProductsByOwners()
    {
        var model = new OwnerViewModel
        {
            // preselect the second owner
            SelectedOwnerId = "2",

            // obviously those come from your database or something
            OwnerList = new[] 
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "owner 1" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "owner 2" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "owner 3" },
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProductsByOwners(OwnerViewModel model)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and you have a corresponding strongly typed view:

```
@model OwnerViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("ProductsByOwners", "Report", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ProductsByOwners" }))
{            
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SelectedOwnerId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.SelectedOwnerId, 
        Model.OwnerList, 
        new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The most common reason the selected item is not selected in the DDL is you've named the selectlist the same as the model.
Strongly typed views are preferred, but it's **fine** to pass the SelectList in a Viewbag. See my tutorial [Working with the DropDownList Box and jQuery](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc) and my blog [Cascading DropDownList in ASP.Net MVC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx)

Comment: Why should this matter? This is quite odd, but was the cause in my case.

Comment: This did it for me. The default control scaffolding names the collection after the property, but in the extremely likely case that you need to do anything more than the template does, it just dies.